# Java access object like array

Tags: java, php

In PHP, there is an ArrayAccess interface which allows you to access an object like an array. Is there a Java-equivalant to this? It would be very handy.

thanks

Comment: [Hashtable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean you want to use:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
int x = foo[10];
```

then no, there's nothing like that in Java. Typically you provide a `get()` method and either `put()` or `set()` depending on the situation.